# Experimenting with styles => No resource found that matches the given name: attr

Tags: android, styles

I try to develop an app for API 8 but do not have any experience with styles.xml. For activities in the app I use Theme.Light. After playing with styles I got the error above. I've also checked other posts on this portal and I tried many suggestions but I could not get further. The styles.xml is below and hopefully someone will come with suggestions.

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

 <style name="ContactLabelTextView">
    <item name="layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="layout_gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="clickable">false</item>
    <item name="longClickable">false</item>
    <item name="textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ContactMultiplineText" >
    <item name="layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace.

Comment: Please take a look at http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/ Maybe it will help you understand styling

Answer (score 1):

After reading the post [recommended by Alexander Zhak](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/) I have better understanding of styles.  Therefore, I made some modifications to my styles.xml and it works. Those modifications are:

```
... 
<style name="ContactLabelTextView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:longClickable">false</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
</style>

<style name="ContactLabelTextView.Layout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ContactMultiplineText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
</style>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `parent style` to enable you to call the attributes of it.

**sample:**

```
 <style name="ContactLabelTextView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
```

The above code is used when you want your `textView` as a **Medium** size text, you can still change it what ever size you want for your `TextView`.